# How to check who or what is using up the RAM?

Tags: ram

I am using a shared workstation. Typing `free -h` returns me

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            31G         30G        232M        292M        1.0G        608M
Swap:          2.0G        997M        1.0G
```

How do I check what processes or who is using the memory?

Comment: Ubuntu also uses memory for disk/file buffers, so it'll always look like memory is fully used. Are you having a specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use top (just type "top"). A "better top" is htop - just install it:

```
sudo apt install htop
```

... and use it

```
htop
```